# How can I migrate repositories from GitLab 7.9.0 to GitLab Community Edition 11.8.3?

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab

I need to migrate 100 repositories from GitLab 7.9.0 to GitLab Community Edition 11.8.3. Can anyone help to do the same?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you are updating the Gitlab version of one instance you will not have to migrate the repositories.

Comment: GitLab 7.9.0 is running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version. I have setup GitLab Community Edition 11.8.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version. So, I need to migrate repositories from the old server to the new one.

Comment: Then you could just clone them, change the git remote to the new one and push, per repository.

Comment: Cloning all these repositories and change git remote is a time taking process. Have any other methods?

Comment: Why don't you prepare a script? it should be pretty straight forward, specially if you use: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have different namespaces in my gitlab server. So, I used ```gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos``` command to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I used `gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos` command to restore all repositories and which worked without any issues. Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/import.html

Old server  (Source installation)

```
tar -cvzf repositories_27-3-2019.tar.gz  -C /home/git/ ./repositories
scp repositories_27-3-2019.tar.gz sijo@10.10.10.178:/home/sijo
```

New server (Omnibus installation)

```
tar -xvf repositories_27-3-2019.tar.gz -C /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/
chown -R git:git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories_27-3-2019/

gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos['/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories_27-3-2019']
```

Note: Only repositories will get restored by using this command.